# LibGDX - android studio: Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DependencyFactory$ClassPathNotation'

Tags: java, android, html, gradle, libgdx

I have the following problem:

If I create a new project with LIBGDX Project Setup (latest version 1.11.0) and then open it in Android Studio, I can upgrade to Gradle 7.4.2 without any problems.
However, when upgrading to Gradle 8.0.1 I always get the same error: "Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DependencyFactory$ClassPathNotation'."
"org/gradle/api/internal/artifacts/dsl/dependencies/DependencyFactory$ClassPathNotation"

It must have something to do with HTML, because if I create a LIBGDX setup without HTML, I can update to Gradle 8.0.1 without any problems. Everything works fine without HTML.

Android Studio Flamingo Patch 2, LIBGDX Setup Version 1.11.0

Would be grateful for help...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will first have to update `org.gretty:gretty:3.0.7` to version `4.0.3`, then the Gradle upgrade will work fine.

---

For the corresponding background see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76495472/19980636).

Comment: That worked with the Gretty update "org.gretty:gretty:3.0.7 to version 4.0.3". But how do you get the information about which update you need from time to time when errors occur.
It will always be a never ending search on the net.
No normal person can see through that anymore. Once it chops on one corner, another time on the other.

Comment: @HermannGo I found the solution thanks to the answer from Krokomot where he said it is likely issue with one of the HTML plugins, so I checked the stacktrace and confirmed it is ineeded the case, then I just updated the plugin to version suggested by the IDE and posted it as answer here for people looking for quick solution.

Comment: @Jiří -- I allowed myself to cross-reference our posts.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* For the short and direct answer see [Jiří's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76674810/19980636). The following elucidates the corresponding background.

---

Lets take a look at the error message.

```
Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DependencyFactory$ClassPathNotation'.
```

The guide on [Upgrading your build from Gradle 7.x to 8.0](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html) says that [Internal DependencyFactory was renamed](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#dependency_factory_renamed).

> The internal `org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DependencyFactory` type was renamed to `org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DependencyFactoryInternal`. As an internal type, it should not be used, but for compatibility reasons the inner `ClassPathNotation` type is still available. This name for the type is deprecated and will be removed in Gradle 8.0. The public API for this is on `DependencyHandler`, with methods such as `localGroovy()` providing the same functionality.

That exactly fits the error message you get when updating to Gradle 8. Those internal Gradle APIs are mainly relevant for the developers of Gradle plugins. That's why the above mentioned Upgrading Guide for Gradle recommends in a second step to

> Update your plugins.
>
> Some plugins will break with this new version of Gradle, for example because they use internal APIs that have been removed or changed. The previous step will help you identify potential problems by issuing deprecation warnings when a plugin does try to use a deprecated part of the API.

Now, you have problems with a HTML setup of libGDX, but not with a non-HTML setup, because different plugins are used. Those non-HTML plugins, like the Android Gradle Plugin, are either not affected or have been updated duly. There are, if I'm not mistaken, two plugins one has to apply in a libGDX HTML-project -- the [WAR plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html) and the [GWT plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=gwt). The first one is a Gradle Core plugin and I doubt that it isn't up-to-date. The latter is a custom one and there are various implementations to choose from, as you can see.

So -- Ensure, that all your plugins are up-to-date. If that doesn't help and you need a HTML-setup of libGDX you probably have to stick with Gradle 7 for now.

Comment: [rant]
So in other words, one project breaking another that relies on it. I might hate Microsoft but if there is one thing they do right is that they don't break the API all the time, not even the unofficial one. -.-
[/rant]

Comment: Welcome to a form of our beloved dependency hell ^^